# Restrict numbers in sequence

Tags: custom-list, multiline-text-field

I have a text box in a New Form (list) on SharePoint 2013 and I am looking for it to recognize (assuming using column validation) 8 and/or 16 digits in sequence and provide a warning that this is not allowed as either a pop up or text alert below the text box.

Essentially looking to restrict account numbers from being entered into the sharepoint with other text. Example : process reversal of fee on account 12345678 - (this should initialize a warning or restriction) and allow the submitter to change to only include the last 4 digits.

Any thoughts or way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use SharePoint Designer, and only need the validation in a form, you can use a Regular Expression in the New or Edit forms by using the Manage Rules feature.

You cannot not do this using a Calculated Column.

You can add custom JavaScript, also using Regular Expressions, to the page to validate the form field or a SharePoint list column.

The above solutions will not migrate well, or at all, to newer versions of SharePoint or SharePoint Online.

The regular expression might look like \d{8}|\d{16}
The above would also match "12345678abc". You could create one to look for eight or sixteen digits with a non-digit before and after.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the field to only numbers, make it a Number fied:

[image]

To restrict the field to only 8 digits, specify the min and max values:
[image]

To provide a hint for the users, use the Description field:

[image]

To limit the field to entering either exactly 8 or exactly 16 digits, use this validation formula:

```
=OR((LEN(Validated)=8),(LEN(Validated)=16))
```

[image]

To provide users with a hint in case they entered wrong data, use the "User message field" under Column validation:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the issue is we cannot store account numbers on our SharePoint Environments. The textbox is for the submitter to describe the request. The reason I am looking to restrict it is so the submitter cannot accidentally include full account numbers